# Are there division rings for which matrices over those rings form division rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Say $R$ is a ring with division. Define $\mathcal{M}_2(R)$ to be the set of 2x2 matrices over $R$ with $\mathcal{M}_2(R)$ a ring.

For what $R$ will $\mathcal{M}_2(R)$ ever be a division ring?

It is easy to show that $\mathcal{M}_2(R)$ is an identity ring, if $R$ itself is an identity ring. Take
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
Where $0$ is $R$'s additive identity and $1$ $R$'s multiplicative identity.

However if we take $\mathbb{R}$ as $R$, there will be entries in $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ that are not invertible, e.g.
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
But $\mathbb{R}$ is a field so it's a division ring.

And so it got me thinking if there are any $R$ out there, that are also division rings, for which $\mathcal{M}_2(R)$ is also a division ring.

Apologies if this is a bit too obvious, or my premise is flawed, I'm only just getting to grips with rings.

Comment: There are always zero divisors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix $e=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ you gave as an example will never be invertible.  It satisfies $e^2=e$ and if it were invertible, we could cancel and get $e=Id$, which is false.  In fact, $e$ is a zero divisor already since $(I_2-e)e=0$, and neither $e$ nor $I_2-e$ are zero.

Of course, zero divisors are not invertible in nontrivial rings with identity.  If $a,b$ are nonzero and $ab=0$ and $a$ is a unit, then $b=0$ (a contradiction) after multiplying with the inverse of $a$ on the left. One could only conclude the assumption that $a$ is a unit is not possible.

So in general, a matrix ring over any ring with identity, with $n > 1$ will never be a division ring.

Another easy zero divisor is this: if you form the matrix that’s $1$ in the upper right hand corner and $0$ elsewhere, it’ll satisfy $A^2=0$.

$M_n(R)$ will be a division ring precisely when $n=1$ and $R$ is a division ring.

Comment: Sorry, just in your first paragraph, what do you mean by that matrix never being invertible? Isn't it its own inverse? And if it's denoted by $e$, what is $Id$ here? Thank you.

Comment: @user16555 $e$ is the matrix you wrote, and $Id$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, in this case.  You can’t get $ey=Id$ for any $y$ at all.

Comment: Right, I see, what would $Id$ look in this case? With $e$, I was just trying to generalise $I_2$ for any ring and assumed that is $Id$.

Comment: You don't get to choose $Id$. It is the identity in your ring, here $Id = I_n$, the unit matrix with $1$ on the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: It is perhaps easier to see that a ring can't be a division ring if it has non-zero zero-divisors. The matrix you mention is such an example.

Comment: @ε--δ thank you! we haven't gotten to zero divisors but I get it now, if I think of it in those terms